# Outlook Web Access not indexing recent emails?

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

My mom works in a small consulting office and they're running exchange server 2007, I think. Anyway, she's visiting me from out of town, and so tech support falls to me.

She's using Outlook Web Access to get to her email. It seems that it's stopped indexing all emails after June 22 for search. They're perfectly findable via scrolling through the folders, just not via search.

She was out of the office on June 22 and 23, and she wasn't using Outlook (the normal interface) during that time. I've done my best googling this stuff, but I know nothing about exchange.

Their IT guy is useless--saying he doesn't know how to deal with Macs. (But this is clearly a cross-platform issue, being a webapp and all.) Is there anything I can do on my end? Is there anything I can tell this IT guy.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell their tech support guy that you tried it on your Windows machine and the same problem arose with the webmail, which rules out the fact that you're using a Mac (not that this is relevant at all).

The phrase:

> small consulting office

would indicate to me that their tech team is probably just one guy who ended up in that role and probably doesn't really know much about in-depth exchange troubleshooting, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. Lying is definitely the plan. The guy is actually a freelancer/consultant type himself. i.e. he was hired because he claims to specialize in this kind of thing. At least, he seems to have handled their migration from an inhouse server to an off-site solution some months back.